# Do transpired solar collectors use both visible light and infrared waves to produce heat?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Because black non-glazed transpired solar collectors absorb both visible light and infrared waves, are both waves equal in stimulating heat?

Comment: I believe both have an effect on a TSC. I would imagine that the infrared wavelengths would be doing more heating than the visible, considering like half of the solar radiation output is infrared. I also imagine it's more reliant on the air surrounding the steel. Water can trap a lot of energy, so if anything it is the water in the air that is doing the collecting.

Comment: First I did not disclose that I was talking about a non-conductive transpired solar collector, one made of black woven cloth that uses the natural openings at each tape's intersection when the wefts and warps overlap and create a very small opening in the collector surface. But....Are you saying you believe a modicum amount of solar heat that is trapped by water molecules and then hits the surface of a TSC can actually be extracted when the ambient air is pulled through the collector sans the water molecules themselves?

Comment: honestly, I have scarce knowledge in this field, that was the only type of TSC I knew of. But anyway, sort of. What I'm saying is that since a TSC uses the air as a conductor of heat, the humidity in the air probably governs some portion of heat flow.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [spectrum of radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg) from the sun (yellow)  and what reaches the ground (red):

[image]

Integratng by eye it seems that about equal amounts of energy reach the ground, visible to infared, so it will depend on the absorption properties of the solar collector. I expect it will have been engineered to be equally efficient in the whole region.